# I can solve it/ can see the car

Tags: modal-verbs

Context: In a math class,

Teacher: solve this problem.

After some time, when the students are still trying:

Teacher to one of his students: John, **can** you solve it? (He is basically asking John whether John thinks his approach till now has been correct and he's soon going to get a solution)

John: Yes, sir. (= I **can** solve it)

Q: Is there any difference between the uses of "can" in (a) and (b) below?

a) John: I **can** (=am able to) solve it. (in the context given above; John says this *while solving the problem*)

b) John: I **can** (=am able to) see the car. (in response to "can you see the car"; John says this *while looking at the car*)

Comment: They are the same use of *can*.

Comment: Pragmatically, 'I can solve this' must be read by an outsider as 'I'm _pretty sure ... almost certain_ that given time I will be able to solve this', whereas 'I can see this' (unless lying say is involved) indicates absolute certainty.

Comment: Modals with some verbs, like sense verbs or _speak_ (a language) can be equivalent to the verbs merely by asserting the possibility. _I can see/hear/smell/taste/feel `X`_ means the same as _I see/hear/smell/taste/feel `X`_. And _I can speak Lithuanian_ means the same as _I speak Lithuanian_. It's not clear (to me, at least) whether these are facts about modality or facts about those particular verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler: For my money, there should normally be a semantic difference depending on the choice of modal verb in something like *I **can / could** calculate pi to 20 decimal places*. Using ***can*** there very strongly implies I've done that calculation at least once in the past, where ***could*** tends to imply ***...if I wanted to** [but so far I've just never felt like actually **doing** it].* Not having any modal at all there *(I calculate pi to 20 places)* seems by default to reference a third possibility (that I do that calculation *regularly / routinely*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you say: *Using **can** there very strongly implies I've done that calculation at least once in the past, where **could** tends to imply ...if I **wanted** to*. But can't we also use: *I **can** calculate...if I **want** to*, just like ***could, wanted***, to suggest that the speaker, for example, has seen a You Tube video of how to calculate *pi* to 20 decimal places or seen its calculation on a website etc., **but has never done before the calculations themselves**?

Comment: @Mr.X: In my *exact* context, ***can*** "very strongly" implies "am able to, **and have done so**", but it's at least *possible* to override the implication of having actually done it. And if I *slightly* change the context, to *I **can write a computer program** to calculate pi to 20 decimals*, I think most people would agree that the meaning there is normally going to be identical to the same with ***could*** (i.e. - I *haven't yet* written any such program, but I *could* do).

Comment: It's easy for me to visualize this because we do use both the "can" meanings in our own native language: one for general contexts and the other for more specific contexts :)